# How to get number only by running the command in the latest version of Selenium IDE Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

By running below command in [Selenium IDE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en). I manage to get this sentence, "**Your booking ID is 1234**". I stored the sentence in a variable called ***myText***

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Command</th>
    <th>Target</th> 
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>store text</td>
    <td>xpath=//div[@id='booking']/div/div[3]</td>
    <td>myText</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can i get only the number and want to store it in a variable for later use? Do i need to use javascript or just manipulate the xpath?

Note: The number is dynamic

Thanks!

Comment: Number length is fixed?

Comment: number length is dynamic

Answer (score 2):

If the text `Your booking ID is` is always same than you can use like:

```
substring-after(//div[@id='booking']/div/div[3], 'Your booking ID is ')
```

**input:**

```
<html>
    <div id="booking">
        <div>
            <div>bla bla bla</div>
            <div>bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Your booking ID is 1234</div>
            <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

**XPath using XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(//div[@id='booking']/div/div[3], 'Your booking ID is ')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
1234
```

see below link: 
http://xsltransform.net/gVAjbSz

Answer (score 0):

Use substring-after

```
substring-before(substring-after('//div[@id='booking']/div/div[3]','Your booking ID is '),'/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Xpath 2.0?

```
translate(//div[@id='booking']/div/div[3], replace(//div[@id='booking']/div/div[3], '\d', ''), '')
```